# NSSort descriptor of CoreData NSSet Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsset

I am passing my NSMutableArray of CoreData object which happens to be an NSSet, currently I am passing it to the array like this

```
tableViewMArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[cardNumber.cNumbers allObjects]];
```

I would like to know how to use a SortDescriptor on it? all of the values in the set are strings that are of numerical values some separated by a slash.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your NSSet:

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]];
NSArray *sortedArray = [[recipes allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```